# bootstrap карусель как узнать ее параметры, методы, события

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, bootstrap

Привет всем!

Попросили немного преукрасить карусель на сайте.
Используется `bootstrap`, никогда раньше не сталкивался.
По коду подключается этот самый бутсрап и все.
Карусель подключается так:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({});
```

Как посмотреть что это за карусель, какие у нее параметры, какие события?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ничего в js не прописано, значит используются дефолтные настройки(скорее всего так оно и есть).

Слайдер бутстрапа очень стандартной настройки и имеет самые минимальные параметры. Для сложного поведения обычно его не используют и подключают/пишут другой.

В [документации бутсрапа](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/) описано то, что вы ищете. Функционал скудный: у него доступно всего [5 свойств](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#options), [7 методов](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#methods), [2 события 4 свойства](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#events). Увы это всё. Хотите более широкой настройки, либо дописывайте сами, либо используйте другой слайдер.

Comment: Спасибо, kizoso